# ASP .net MVC Jqgrid data binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid with a column named 'Comments'. My controller code returns data as follows:

```
var jsonData = new
{
rows=
....
....
   select new
             {
             col1....
             col2....
             Comments = _Model.GetComments(id),
             })

.......
.....
   return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

_Model.GetComments(id) will return a ClientComments Object which has a few properties say CommentID, FirstName, MiddleName etc., which will be bound to each row in the grid

Now in my jqgrid I need to build a tool tip based on Comments column properties and for that I need to use the properties of my Comments in JQGrid for each row. May I know How I can manipulate Comment's properties for each row? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried in my javascript that for each row rowObject.Comments.FirstName and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

For the JavaScript version of the grid you would use `getDataIDs` to get the ID of each row, and then use `getRowData` to read the data at that row. For example:

```
var ids = $("#grid").getDataIDs();
for(var i=0; i<ids.length;i++){
   var rowdata = $("#grid").getRowData(ids[i]);

   // Build tooltip here using rowdata.FirstName, rowdata.MiddleName, etc.
}
```

But, are you working with the JavaScript version of jqGrid or jqGrid ASP.NET component?

Comment: Hi Justin,
THanks for ur help again. I missed a very basic point that some comments might be null. So in my javascript i should first check if(rowObject.Comments != null. Only then I can access rowObject.Comments.whateverproperties in that object. So it works fine now.